# How to Display array list in another Activity?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I have one EditText which values i want to store with a button click in an array, in second Activity i want to display these values in Listview. I have some problems with storing and displaying values in another activity.

Comment: What you have done so far and post your error log also.

Comment: You could take a look at shared view models https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing

Answer (score 0):

Use callback.

in ClassA with the stringList:
Create interface

```
MyCallback callback;

viod setCallback(MyCallback callback){
this.callback = callback;
}
viod onStop(){
    callback = null;
}

interface MyCallback{
    void doSomething(String string);
}
```

in ClassB:
implement MyCallback

```
public class ClassB implements ClassA.MyCallback
```

set reference in onCreate

```
ClassA classA = new ClassA();
classA.setCallback(this);
```

// override method doSomething

```
@override
void doSomething(String string){
 //get your string from your EditText…
}
```

when the job is done inside class A call:

```
callback.doSomething(string);
```

destroy reference inside class B in onStop()

```
classA.onStop();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an intent when starting the second Activity from your button click.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("EXTRA_ARRAY", arrayList);
startActivity(intent);
```

In your second activity...

```
List<String> arrayList = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("EXTRA_ARRAY");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a static arrayList inside your activity like that :

```
class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    public static ArrayList yourArray;

    @Override
    void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        .......

        // you can use you array to display its content

    }

}
```

**and inside your button action do like that**

```
botton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener{
    @Override
    void onClick(View view){

        YourActivity.yourArray = this.arrayList;

        startActivity(new Intent(getContext , YourActivity.class));
    }
});
```